# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized VB

Tags: vb.net

Getting an error here not sure why its not opening the connection. Hoping someone can help me.

```
 Protected Sub Btn_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Submit.Click
    Dim Sqlstr As String
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=DB\TEST;Initial Catalog=Orders;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand(Sqlstr, con)
    Sqlstr = "insert into customers(FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Address,City,State,Zip) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Phone,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip)"
    Try
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName.Text()
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@LastName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Email.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Phone", Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Phone.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Address", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Address.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@City", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = City.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@State", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = State.Text
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Zip", Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Zip.Text
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: You need to assign the connection to the command. Or, use `cmdInsert = connection.CreateCommand()`.

Comment: Therefore use only the using statement for connections(or everything else implementing `IDisposable`). You don't need to declare the connection first. That's just a source for such errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong scope -- you're instantiating your `SqlCommand` before instantiating and opening the actual SQL connection you're trying to use to execute the command.

I believe this is what will fix your code (I moved the insert call into the `using` scope):

```
Protected Sub Btn_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Submit.Click
Dim Sqlstr As String
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=DB\TEST;Initial Catalog=Orders;Integrated Security=True"
Sqlstr = "insert into customers(FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Address,City,State,Zip) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Phone,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip)"

Try
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        connection.Open()

        Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand(Sqlstr, connection)  <----- **** Moved this here, changed the connection

        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName.Text()
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@LastName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Email.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Phone", Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Phone.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Address", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Address.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@City", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = City.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@State", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = State.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Zip", Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Zip.Text
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connection.Close()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two SqlConnection objects - one in Dim con As SqlConnection and then another in your using statement. Create the SqlCommand after the using statement and pass the connection in to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Protected Sub Btn_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Submit.Click
    Dim Sqlstr As String

    ' =================================================
    ' This is a declaration, not an instantiation
    ' =================================================
    Dim con As SqlConnection      

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=DB\TEST;Initial Catalog=Orders;Integrated Security=True"

    ' =================================================
    ' con is Nothing here
    ' =================================================
    Dim cmdInsert As New SqlCommand(Sqlstr, con)     

    Sqlstr = "insert into customers(FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Address,City,State,Zip) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Phone,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip)"
    Try

        ' =================================================
        ' connection is not what you passed to cmdInsert
        ' =================================================
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection Sting Property Error always occur when the connection is not declared/renewed

the solution is simple

```
dim con as new SqlConnection 
con.connectionString = "Provide your SQL connection"
con.open
'write code or action you want to perform
con.close
```

Hope it helps.